# Is it possible to draw WPF control over HwndHost control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, com

Is it possible to draw control over HwndHost control?(I don't want to use popups)

This HwndHost control draws over any WPF control. As I understand it doesn't depend on ZIndex.(because HwndHost control is drawn by COM)

If you want to play with this control you could get more information about it and download samples [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2007/10/07/5354351.aspx).

[image]

Comment: Is this about drag/drop (the "drag" in your title), or about Z-order (the "draw control over HwndHost" in your question)? I'm guessing the "drag" is a typo...

Comment: Yes) You are right. It was typo. I've already corrected it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question, no. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on WPF and Win32 Interoperation.

From above article:

> •HwndHost will appear on top of other WPF elements in the same top-level window. However, a ToolTip or ContextMenu generated menu is a separate top-level window, and so will behave correctly with HwndHost

Comment: Maybe is it possible to HACK it in someway? I have read this article and I wan't to find another solution if is it possible. Too much stuff in my application depends on it.

Comment: I am not aware of any hacks to do so. I think the operative words are top-level window. "The HwndHost Control has a separate HWND and will **always** be drawn on top of WPF elements" according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744952.aspx

Comment: Thanks... I've read about that. So.. I'll mark your post as an answer.